# Drop P-frame when decoding/encoding mp4 video

Tags: ffmpeg, frame, encode, mp4, libx264

I'm decoding/encoding the same mp4 (video/mp4) file using ffmpeg (libAV library) + libx264 encoder. For example, the original video file contains 182 frames:

```
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4a843ce00] frame I:2     Avg QP:17.95  size: 13834
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4a843ce00] frame P:180   Avg QP:19.90  size:  6297
```

but after the followig decoding/encoding I'm getting file contains 181 frames:

```
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4ac421dc0] frame I:2     Avg QP:17.93  size: 13627
[libx264 @ 0x7fb4ac421dc0] frame P:179   Avg QP:19.77  size:  5946
```

I've already tried to change AVCodecContext gop_size/max_b_frames/priv_data (profile, preset, tune, x264opts)
and I've also read these posts and tried to solve my problem:

[ffpmeg drops last frame when compressing from MP4 to MP4 (libx264)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031167/ffpmeg-drops-last-frame-when-compressing-from-mp4-to-mp4-libx264)

[ffmpeg/libx264 C API: frames dropped from end of short MP4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177897/ffmpeg-libx264-c-api-frames-dropped-from-end-of-short-mp4)

**UPD**: If I set framerate and timebase = 26/1 and 1/26 and more - frame doesn't drop.

**UPD2**: Solved!

```
//in function avformat_open_input() add AVDictionary *options:
av_dict_set(&options, "r", "25", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "ignore_editlist", "1", 0);
```

I expected decoding/encoding videos with all the frames (without changed parameters).

Comment: You should post the working solution as Answer, could help future readers.

Comment: @VC.One just add this for decoder in function avformat_open_input():  AVDictionary *options:
av_dict_set(&options, "r", "25", 0);
av_dict_set(&options, "ignore_editlist", "1", 0);